# Python 3.4 subprocess FileNotFoundError WinError 2

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I'm using Python 3.4, and I'm trying to run the most simple command:`subprocess.call(["dir"])`.

If I run `subprocess.call(["dir"])`  I get the following - `FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified`.

How can I fix this? I tried installing `subprocess` with `pip`, but it seems to be impossible.

Comment: Well, the file *wasn't* found - there's nothing named `dir` (or even `dir.exe`) on a standard Windows system, it's a built-in feature of `cmd.exe`.  You'd have to add `shell=True` to your `subprocess.call()` to get it to run the command via `cmd.exe`, where the `dir` command can be found.

Comment: @jasonharper That was it! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to not use shell=True as it is a security risk.

Also, you might want to get the result of subprocess.call, error messages and exit code to handle errors.

At last, always use a timeout on commands so your program won't get stuck (or thread them).

Here's a quick and dirty version you can use

```py
import os
import subprocess

# Your command
command = 'dir'

# Forge your command using an absolute path
shell_command = '"%s" /c %s' % (os.path.join(os.environ['SYSTEMROOT'], 'system32', 'cmd.exe'), command)
try:
    # Execute the command with a timeout, and redirct error messages to your output
    output = subprocess.check_output(shell_command, timeout=10, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=False, universal_newlines=True)
    exit_code = 0
# Handle possible errors and get exit_code
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as exc:
    output = ""
    exit_code = exc.returncode

# Show results
print('[%s] finished with exit code %s\nResult was\n\n%s' % (command, exit_code, output))
```